# System.DataRowView Error al cargar ComboBox C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Yo tengo el mismo problema amigos, entiendo como funciona el `DataTable` pero cuando estoy intentando cargar un `ComboBox` a través de una consulta que contiene 2 tablas me muestra el `System.DataRowView`

```
private void CargarComboCentrales()
{
    DataTable dt = null;
    string query = "";
   query = @"SELECT C.idCentral, E.nombreEdificio
            FROM Centrales C INNER JOIN Edificios E
            ON C.idEdificio=E.idEdificio
            ORDER BY E.nombreEdificio";

    if (Auxiliar.conexion.SqlSelectDataTable(query, ref dt))
    {
        cmbIdCentral.ValueMember = "C.idCentral";
        cmbIdCentral.DisplayMember = "E.nombreEdificio";
        cmbIdCentral.DataSource = dt;
    }

}
```

Cuando ejecuto la consulta en SQLServer funciona muy bien. Y no veo ningun ejemplo de cargar combobox a traves de un inner join.

Si alguien me ayuda os agradeceria mucho.
PD:*Cuando la información esta en una misma tabla si carga el combo sin problemas.

Tablas>

Edificios:

```
idEdificio
nombreEdificio
zonaEdificio
direccion
```

Centrales:

```
idCentral
idEdificio
extension
marca
modelo
```

Quisiera cargar el idCentral con el nombre del edificio

Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que has depurado y ves que el contenido de la `DataTable` es el correcto, yo haría lo siguiente:

```
if (Auxiliar.conexion.SqlSelectDataTable(query, ref dt))
{
    cmbIdCentral.DataSource = dt;
    //Supongo que hasta aquí la variable dt contiene los valores necesarios
    cmbIdCentral.ValueMember = "idCentral";
    cmbIdCentral.DisplayMember = "nombreEdificio";

}
```

Me da la impresión que al usar los nombres que le das a las tablas en la consulta( `C.idCentral` y `E.nombreEdificio`) no esta reconociendo los nombres de las columnas del resultado.

Prueba esto y me comentas.

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo amigo... Voy a intentar cargar el DataSource antes de asignarle el value y display member.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, si me funciona.
Ya entendi.
A pesar de estar haciendo un llamado a 2 tablas, el DataTable me busca el nombre de la columna de mi BD y no hay ninguna que se nombre C.idCentral ni E.nombreEdificio.

Gracias de verdad <3

Comment: @Nor De nada, te agradecería que marcases las respuesta como valida para futuras consultas de otros usuarios. Un saludo